# Pascal list issue

Tags: pascal

I'm facing an issue connected with lists in Pascal right now.
When I add a person it goes successfully, but when I want to add next person it throws an error: [image]

Ide: Lazarus.

Code (at the start of the code the head is equal to nil):

```
TYPE

  Person = RECORD
    name: STRING[15];
    last_name: STRING[15];
    age: INTEGER;
  end;

  pListElement = ^ListElement;

  ListElement = RECORD
    person: ^Person;
    next: pListElement;
  end;




PROCEDURE AddPerson(var head: pListElement);
PROCEDURE ShowPersons(var head: pListElement);



implementation

PROCEDURE AddPerson(var head: pListElement);
 Var NewPerson: pListElement;
   Begin
     new(NewPerson);
     Write(' Podaj imie: ');
     readln(NewPerson^.Person^.name);
     Write(' Podaj nazwisko: ');
     readln(NewPerson^.Person^.last_name);
     Write(' Podaj wiek: ');
     readln(NewPerson^.Person^.age);
     if (head = NIL) THEN
     begin
       head:= NewPerson;
       NewPerson^.next:= nil;
     end else
     begin
       NewPerson^.next:= head;
       NewPerson:= head;
     end;
   End;


  PROCEDURE ShowPersons(var head: pListElement);
   Begin
    if (head <> NIL) THEN
      begin
        WriteLn(' | ', head^.Person^.name:15, ' | ', head^.Person^.last_name:15, ' | ', head^.Person^.age:3, '  |');
        ShowPersons(head^.next);
      end;
    End;
```

Comment: We can't see your screen.  What exact line is executing when the error occurs?

Comment: The ide is not telling which line. The screen is visible.

Comment: Well, I find it surprising it cannot tell you which line.  Anyway, if that's the case, do what we used to do in the old days - comment  out all the lines in your procedure, then re-introduce them one by one until the error recurs.

Comment: The debugger tells you exactly which line is causing the problem. Learn to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you make a new ListElement record in Addperson, you then assume the Person is magically initialized. It isn't. It needs to be looked up or created (new()'ed), depending on what it is actually good for.

Comment: I don't get it, so I should also create new person? Or what?

Comment: I don't know. You made Person a pointer. Why didn't you put the person fields directly in listelement? The way you do now could be because e.g. when multiple ListElement items can point to the same person or something like that.

Comment: You need two New()s.  One for the `NewPerson` pListElement and one for the `person` pointer it contains.  They are both pointers, and so need memory to be allocated to them, which is what New() does.